# Going offline on Facebook

Tags: facebook, nokia-lumia-820

How can I become invisible or turn off chat in Facebook? Settings on the desktop doesn't affect the phone, and it turns on visibility automatically. I appear online 24x7. Is there a way I can appear invisible even when using Facebook on the phone?

PS: I am using [Nokia Lumia 820](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_Lumia_820), if that matters.

Comment: Integrated facebook chat or facebook app?

Comment: Integrated facebook chat in the Messages

Comment: You can change the `SET CHAT STATUS` to `offline`.

Comment: oh.. there's setting in the messages for that. Silly me. Thanks :-)

Comment: I'm posting it as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the `SET CHAT STATUS` to `offline`. You can find this setting in `Messaging`' or `People` > `Me`.